# Floating objects: defining in a place, saying where to print later

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

I'm using a system where I can mix TeX and formal definitions, and it has a procedure that generates latex that combining my TeX and the formal definitions. I discovered that I can wrap the formal definitions in figures or tables, and make them to float in the page.

Is there any package where I can define the figures in one place, using a constructor like:

```
\figuredefinition[1]{
....
}
```

and later on on the document I could use something like

```
\printfigure[1]
```

This would allow me

- To have floating objects (figures/tables) precisely positioned in the document;
- Add text in the place where these figures would appear
- Introduce the *wrapped* formal definitions in the order accepted by the system (Isabelle/HOL), and print these definitions in a place more suitable for human consumption.

Any suggestions of what I could use to obtain this functionality?

Thank you very much,

Diego Dias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newsavebox\pickie


\begin{document}

\savebox{\pickie}{\begin{tikzpicture} \draw[fill] (0,0) circle(15mm);\end{tikzpicture}}


\lipsum

\begin{figure}[h!]
\usebox{\pickie}
\caption{This is not much of a picture}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi JPi, thank you very much for your quick answer. That does exactly what I'm looking for. Interestingly, Isabelle (the tool I'm using to generate the tex) seems to clear the memory of the latex compiler when compiling each of the generated tex files -- that's the only reasonable hypothesis I can make to explain the fact that a savebox defined in one file in Isabelle cannot be referred in other files.

Comment: The tikz package is irrelevant.  I just used it to create an example picture.  Replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: Independent of this, your suggestion was superb, it actually directs my focus to the right point. I'm also trying to wrap definitions on \newcommand, so that the definitions are processed by Isabelle, and during the generation of latex they get hidden from a part of the document. Now I'll actually investigate how I'll make the commands defined in one part of the document to persist over the whole document. Thanks!!

Comment: What is Isabelle?

Comment: Isabelle/HOL is a theorem prover (https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/) that supports the concept of formal documents (verified documents). It's the tool I am using that allows to have formal definitions mixed with latex.

Comment: By using Isabelle, I can make sure that every formula mentioned in the text is type checked, and every theorem is indeed proved. The problem is that while using Isabelle I have to introduce the concepts following the principle definition-before-use, which I think is not the best to explain concepts while writing.